# How can I "ping" the user in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ajax, xml, ping

I need to get the request time it took the client to reach the server and the opposite.
And so I have been able to do this in Python which does not help me now on a webpage.

So I heard that it can be done using Ajax, is that true?

If so, Can you give me some details or information where I should start from?

Thank you, looking forward to a answer!

Comment: If it is for troubleshooting purposes you can use firebug to see the request time. https://getfirebug.com/network

Answer (score 1):

You could emulate a ping via http however that is not very accurate. A simple way would be to post the current timespamp in ms or ns and wait then for the response of the same time. The difference between the real time and time of the response is the so called round trip time (RTT). If you divide it by two you get the response time what the ping is.

Comment: What do you mean "to post the current time stamp" is this something that can be done using Ajax?

Comment: On the client side you know the time of the client. As long not all clocks are synchronized you need to use the time of the client only.

Comment: How do I know his loading time?

Comment: 1. You post the current time to the server. 2. The server responses that time as fast as possible back to the client. 3. The client compairs the time between the responsed initial time and the current time. 4. The difference is the RTT. If you divde the RTT by two you get the response time aka ping.

Answer (score 0):

On newer browsers, you can use the [navigation timing API](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/webperf/raw-file/tip/specs/NavigationTiming/Overview.html) ([HTML5 rocks article on navigation timing](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webperformance/basics/)) to get a fine-grained break down of the time that it takes to load your page. You can simply subtract the relevant fields from "performance.timing" to get the timing that you are interested in. The `(secureConnectionStart - connectStart)` or `(connectEnd - connectStart)`, depending on whether the connection is an SSL connection, looks like a reasonable approximation of ping time (though, as rekire@ points out, you probably want to include more than just that if you are trying to measure the overall user-visible latency of your website for end users).

Comment: What language can I program this in? Ajax? Html5?

Comment: @user2634624 This is a JavaScript API. Ajax is a particular technique, not a programming language (it is generally referring to JavaScript, but it also applies in client-side languages that compile to JavaScript like Dart). HTML5 is somewhat of a nebulous term and, in the loosest sense, encompasses are variety of features in HTML, JavaScript, and CSS. Ajax predates HTML5, however.

Answer (score 0):

For your reference, the ajax ping works as below. 
Unfortunately it is very possible you will get blocked by domain policy and never get a success.

```
function ping(){
   $.ajax({
      url: 'http://website.com',
      success: function(result){
         alert('replied');
      },     
      error: function(result){
          alert('error');
      }
   });
```

Please see [this code](http://jsfiddle.net/GSSCD/203/) as an example of a seemingly successful implementation for what you are trying to do.